# spring boot application is failing to start when i enable swagger

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:
org.springframework.data.rest.core.support.UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory.(UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory.java:57)

The following method did not exist:
org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry.of(Ljava/util/List;)Lorg/springframework/plugin/core/PluginRegistry;
The method's class, org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry, is available from the following locations:
jar:file:/C:/Users/182588/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/plugin/core/PluginRegistry.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

```
org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry: file:/C:/Users/182588/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
```

Action:
Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry

I have added below dependence in the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You should paste the full exception stack info here for other people to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

add this dependency, it may works

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: it is working after adding the above dependency